need help making the stars transparent so that i can see the gradient background behind everything. using adobe illustrator
need help making the stars transparent so that i can see the gradient background behind everything. behind the stars is a bunch of random rectangles i used to fill in that shape. I am using adobe illustrator.


Select everything except the green background, and choose the Shape Builder tool, then hold down Alt as you click to cut it out the white stars.

Several ways....

Select the stars and the flag, choose Object > Compound Path > Make (depends on construction and won't always work)
Select just the stars, Object > Compound Path > Make, then select stars and flag and hit the Minus Front button on the Pathfinder Panel
Select stars and flag, grab the Shape Builder Tool, hold down the Option/Alt key and then click each star.

